# jQuery - Loop through data options

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with jQuery's [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method to store some extra data on an anchor tag.

```
<a href="/someurl/" class="someLink" data-options="{'checkout_authentication':'create_account', 'foo':'bar'}">Link</a>
```

I see by the example given that I can access the data attribute like so:

```
$("a.someLink").data("options").foo
```

Where "foo" would be the name of one of the keys. That works great, but I will not always know what data attributes exist so I cannot call them specifically. I would like to **not** specify the name, only get the entire contents of the data-options attribute and loop through each key to build a query string.

I tried something like the following:

```
var dataOptions = $(this).data('options');

for(var index in dataOptions) {
    console.log(index,dataOptions[index]);
};
```

But that was outputting the following:

[image]

Comment: `$("div").data("options").foo` gives me `undefined`,  are you sure it works for you?

Comment: What you have inside the data-options is a string and not an object. So it assumes it as a string for..in.. loop is iterating over each char.

Comment: @SKS Normally jQuery will use JSON.parse to parse the string and return the object. Only if the string cannot be parsed will jQuery return the string as is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change your html to:

```
<a
  href="/someurl/"
  class="someLink"
  data-options='{"foo":"barski", "bar":"fooski"}'
>Link</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Note the change of quotes for the json string. This is needed as the only valid quotes to use is double quotes.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/p5MGG/1/

Comment: Yeah this was the main issue. Parsing the json is a nice tip (which I will do, once the json is valid). Thanks! (will accept when SO lets me)

Comment: @jyoseph You don't need to use `JSON.parse` if the format is valid. jQuery will do this automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs for jQuery data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

> When the data attribute is an object (starts with '{') or array (starts with '[') then jQuery.parseJSON is used to parse the string; it must follow valid JSON syntax including quoted property names.

Your `data-options` is *not* valid JSON, since it uses `'` instead of `"`. If you change to:

```
<a href="/someurl/" class="someLink" data-options='{"foo":"barski", "bar":"fooski"}'>Link</a>
```

It does what you want.

**Edit:** An alternate approach would be to store your options as individual `data` attributes:

```
<a href="/someurl/" class="someLink" data-foo="barski" data-bar="fooski">Link</a>
```

And iterating over `data()` instead:

```
var options = $(this).data();
```

Answer (score -1):

From your example, it looks like the options returned are being interpreted as a `String`. If you explicitly parse them into object form, your code should produce the expected results:

```
var dataOptions = JSON.parse($("a.someLink").data("options"));

for(index in dataOptions) {
   console.log(index, dataOptions[index]);
};
```

Comment: Also, note that your JSON will need to be properly formatted for this to work. That means using double-quotes around both keys and values throughout (see Yoshi's answer).